# SqlAlchemy base model in type hintings?

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-typing

In code below what should be instead of `???`? Should it be `Base`? But it looks strange for me.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

metadata = sa.MetaData()

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
    

# another models

    
class Repository:
    # base repository
    
    model: ???
    
    def create(self, **create_data) -> ???:
        pass

    def get(self, pk) -> ???
        pass


class UserRepository(Repository):
    pass


# another repositories
```